# Any possibilities to save HTML file after modyfing it with javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, .net, xhtml

My application generates a local XHTML file in which a syntax highlighting script is run at the opening. Unfortunately the script has more than 200,000 lines to highlight so it can take quite a long time(1-2minutes but still.. :P).
Isn't it possible to run that script just once, overwriting the existing file after execution? or maybe even run it in the background just after I generate that file and overwrite?

I'm using SyntaxHighlighter 3.0.83.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but i think it would work. In IE show the de developer tools. open the page, wait till it shows the right data and then refresh the HTML in the developer tools. It will reread the DOM. Then use the save html option in the developer tool window.